# TextView не работает корректно

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, spannable

Хочу втиснуть в программу текст вроде бы переписал все как должно быть в коде
но ничего у меня не вышло[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел что бы было так как в первом варианте но вышло как втором. 
В первом варианте используют не один `TextView` прочитал много статей и пересмотрел много видео но ни в одном пока не нашел как сделать так как в первом варианте. Постоянно получается как во втором. или ещё хуже. 
Вот как я это написал в `String`

```
<string name="ph_mochi"><b>Норма:</b> 5.0–7.0/n <b>Загальні відомості</b>/n Реакція сечі (рН) залежить від кількості вільних водневих іонів Н+, утворючися в результаті дисоціації органічних та неорганічних кислот. В дистальній частині ниркових канальців іони Н+ виділяються в сечу, де в основном зв\'язуються з буферними основами і тільки не велика частина їх виводиться з сечею в вільному вигляді./n/n Свіжа сеча здорової людини може мати різну реакцію (рН від 4,5 до 8) в звичайних умовах реакція сечі слабколужна (рН 5–6). Коливання рН сечі залежить від складу харчування: м\'ясна дієта обумовлює кислу реакцію сечі, перевага рослиної та молочної їжі призводить до олужнення сечі. Зміни рН сечі відповідає рН крові. При <i>ацидозах</i> сеча має кислу реакцію, при <i>алкалозах</i> лужну. Розходження цих показників призводить до хронічних вражень канальців нирок. /n/n Бактеріальний розклад сечовини в сечоводах чи зберігання сечі при кімнатній температурі призводить до олужнення сечі. Реакція сечі впливає на солеутворення при сечокам\'яної хвороби:/nпри рН ниже 5,5 чаще утворюють сечокислі;/nпри рН від 5,5–6,0 оксалатові;/nпри рН вище 7,0 фосфатні камінці./n<b>ПІДВИЩЕННЯ рН:</b>/n/n•Метаболічний та респіраторний алкалоз/n•Нирковий канальцевий алкалоз/n•Бактеріальне розкладення сечовини/n•При вегетеріанській дієті/n•Гиперкаліємія/n•Хронічна ниркова недостатність/n•Новоутворення органів сечостатевої системи/n•В результаті цитрата натрію, бікарбонатів, альдостерону./n/n<b>ЗНИЖЕННЯ рН:</b>/n•Метаболічний та респіраторний ацидоз/n•Гіпокаліємія/n•Обезводнення/n•Голодання/n•Цукровий діабет/n•Лихоманка/n•Виражена діарея/n•Прийом лікарських препаратів: Аскорбінова кислота, Кортикотропін, Метіонін, Хлорид амонію/n•Дієта з великим вмістом м\'ясного білка, клюкви</string>
```

Может они парсят `json` или сразу с формата `txt` читают эти тексты.
 Раскройте секрет пожалуйста. Может кто то знает видео расширенное по использовании `TextView`

Читал ещё о `SpannableStringBuilder` это оно здесь используется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android Studio Tutorial - Html Text View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFOt9M-2bKs)

Хороший урок по созданию текста на первой версии. 
Нужно написать текст на `HTML` со всеми атрибутами этого языка.

`textView.setHtml("Строка на HTML")` // В ресурсах `String` не сохраняется по причине, что атрибуты языка не со читаются с языком ресурсов `String`